# Reference in caption, errors with make4ht

Tags: cross-referencing, tex4ht, conversion, make4ht

Putting a cross-reference inside a caption prompts a bunch of scary error messages from `make4ht`, though somehow the example still converts. In a larger document, it would abort or hang.

Take this document, `ref.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{An Airplane}
See figure \ref{fig:airplane}.

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Airplane}
    \label{fig:airplane}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{picture}(200,100) % thanks, @DavidCarlisle
        \put(30,40){\line(1,0){150}}
        \put(30,40){\line(0,1){60}}
        \put(30,100){\line(1,0){20}}
        \put(50,100){\line(1,-4){10}}
        \put(60,60){\line(1,0){100}}
        \put(160,60){\line(1,-1){20}}
        \put(100,50){\line(0,-1){80}}
        \put(130,50){\line(0,-1){80}}
        \put(100,-30){\line(1,0){30}}
        \put(100,61){\line(0,1){49}}
        \put(130,61){\line(0,1){49}}
        \put(100,110){\line(1,0){30}}
    \end{picture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\section{A Smaller Airplane}

See figure \ref{fig:airplane2}.

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Smaller airplane (cf. figure \ref{fig:airplane})}
    \label{fig:airplane2}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{picture}(100,50)
        \put(15,20){\line(1,0){75}}
        \put(15,20){\line(0,1){30}}
        \put(15,50){\line(1,0){10}}
        \put(25,50){\line(1,-4){5}}
        \put(30,30){\line(1,0){50}}
        \put(80,30){\line(1,-1){10}}
        \put(50,25){\line(0,-1){40}}
        \put(65,25){\line(0,-1){40}}
        \put(50,-15){\line(1,0){15}}
        \put(50,30){\line(0,1){25}}
        \put(65,30){\line(0,1){25}}
        \put(50,55){\line(1,0){15}}
    \end{picture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It compiles fine with `pdflatex`. Try converting with `make4ht ref`. I get this console output:

```
[37m[STATUS]  [0mmake4ht: Conversion started
[37m[STATUS]  [0mmake4ht: Input file: ref
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: Filename  Line    Message
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 50.
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: Filename  Line    Message
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 50.
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: Filename  Line    Message
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 50.
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
[31m[ERROR]   [0mhtlatex: ./ref.tex     50   Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
[37m[STATUS]  [0mmake4ht: Conversion finished
```

Line 50, referred to in the error messages, is the final line of the second figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX4ht writes the contents of the `\caption` command to an auxiliary file for later use in list of tables, etc. The `\ref` command as redefined by TeX4ht is not robust, so you will get this error. I will fix this in the sources, so it shouldn't be a problem soon. Until then, you can use this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\DeclareDocumentCommand\:ref{s}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\Protect\::ref}{\Protect\::ref}}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It should compile without errors now. This is the result:

[image]

Comment: But the `<span>` HTML tag is missing in the `HTML` file? How to active this?

Comment: @Balaji where is it missing?